# Remove word chapter if there are no figure

Tags: remove

I want remove word chapter from LOF  if there are no figure and each chapter with color ,the same for tables .

[image]

```
    \documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}}%
}

\newcommand{\lofchapter}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\hfill
  \textsc{Chapter #1}\hfill
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\par
  \nobreak
}

\newcommand{\lotchapter}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\hfill
  \textsc{Chapter #1}\hfill
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\par
  \nobreak
}


\renewcommand*{\cftfigurename}{Figure\space} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand*{\cfttablename}{Table\space} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{First figure}\end{table}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Third chapter}


\chapter{Last chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stores the total number of figures and tables per chapter in the aux file, but requires running `\savetotal` at the end of each chapter.  You could modify `\chapter` and use `\AtEndDocument`, but that would be a "lazy man's load."

First you need to construct a list of colors.  The easiest way would be to use `\ifcase` (see Knuth **TeXbook** page 210).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\colorlist}[1]% list index 0,1,...
  {\ifcase#1\relax black\or blue\or red\or green\or yellow\or orange\or purple\else black\fi}% no space after color
  
\newcommand{\chaptercolor}{black}% reserve global name

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savetotal}{\protected@write {\@auxout}{}{\string\xdef\string\totalfigures\roman{chapter}{\arabic{figure}}}%
  \protected@write {\@auxout}{}{\string\xdef\string\totaltables\roman{chapter}{\arabic{table}}}}
  
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{\bgroup
  \@ifundefined{totalfigures\roman{chapter}}{%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}}%
  }{\count1=\csname totalfigures\roman{chapter}\endcsname\relax
  \the\count1
    \ifnum\count1>0
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}}%
    \fi}
  \@ifundefined{totaltables\roman{chapter}}{%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\lotchapter{\thechapter}}%
  }{\count1=\csname totaltables\roman{chapter}\endcsname\relax
    \ifnum\count1>0
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\lotchapter{\thechapter}}%
  }%
\egroup}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\lofchapter}[1]{%
  \xdef\chaptercolor{\colorlist#1}% see \cftfigurename
  \noindent\textcolor{\chaptercolor}{%
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\hfill
  \textsc{Chapter #1}\hfill
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}}%
}

\newcommand{\lotchapter}[1]{%
\xdef\chaptercolor{\colorlist#1}% see \cfttablename
  \noindent\textcolor{\chaptercolor}{%
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\hfill
  \textsc{Chapter #1}\hfill
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}}
}


\renewcommand*{\cftfigurename}{\textcolor{\chaptercolor}{Figure\space}}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand*{\cfttablename}{\textcolor{\chaptercolor}{Table\space}} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{First table}\end{table}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]
\savetotal

\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]
\savetotal

\chapter{Third chapter}

\savetotal
\chapter{Last chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]
\savetotal
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for the code! It works perfectly. Can you please just color "Figure" and "Table" like the chapter headings? Thanks!

Comment: I take it you mean the one in `\cftfigurename`.  I believe that the cft prefix means tocloft, so you might want to read the manual.